# Secure HTTPS connection between arduino yun and apache server - self signed certificate

Tags: tls, curl

I want to secure the connection between my arduino yun and my apache server. Right now I am using a simple get request in order to send information to the server. 
I thought to improve security by using a self signed certificate on apache and using *curl -k*  to send information.

I wanted to ask you, do you think there are any flaws in this procedure? Is the connection secure, or an attacker can intercept the traffic and send data to  the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the long name of `-k` (`--insecure`) implies, that is not a good idea.

The problem with disabling the certificate validation is that it allows for easy MITM attacks, e.g. another machine can intercept the communication and read/modify requests as if it were simple http with little overhead by simply self-signing itself to be the expected host.

Instead: As long as you [pin the certificate](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Certificate_and_Public_Key_Pinning) and a possible attacker cannot tamper with your trust store, your setup should be fine if you do not keep `curl` from verifying the certificate.